# How is this pre-evaluation of a function (or caching of computation) in a callback done in ReatJS's React Transition Group?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, jsx

I notice this strange phenomenon while working with ReactJS's [React Transition Group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group):

Suppose I have a closure like this inside a functional component

```
var _hasEntered = false

const hasEntered = () => {
  return _hasEntered
}
```

with this functional component returning a `<Transition />` imported from `'react-transition-group/Transition'`

```
return (<Transition in={props.isPushed}
    timeout={duration}
    onEntered={() => {
      console.log("_hasEntered is true")
      _hasEntered = true
      console.log("testing getter: " + hasEntered())
    }}
    >
    {(state) => {
      console.log("transition state: "+ state)
      console.log("testing getter inside: " + hasEntered())
      return(
      <div style={transition[state]} >
      {props.content}
      </div>
    )}}
  </Transition>)
```

Suppose the transition starts with `props.isPushed = false`, when we render the component and set `props.isPushed` to `true` for the view to transit in, we'd see the following logs in the console:

```
transition state: exited
testing getter inside: false
transition state: entering
testing getter inside: false
transition state: entered
testing getter inside: false
_hasEntered is true
testing getter: true
```

All is good so far. But things get strange when we set `props.isPushed` back to `false` as the view transits away. `hasEntered()` inside still returns the old value `false`.

```
transition state: exiting
testing getter inside: false
transition state: exited
testing getter inside: false
```

Normally with a callback like this, `hasEntered` should be evaluated during the evaluation of the callback i.e. after `_hasEntered` is set to `true`.So we should be seeing the getter inside returning `true` as well!

```
transition state: exiting
testing getter inside: true
transition state: exited
testing getter inside: true
```

But that is not the case here.

Apparently there is either some strange caching happening here or that `hasEntered()` is being pre-evaluated before the callback that takes `state` as a parameter.

I haven't got the time to dig into the source yet (just taking a short break from work now to write this post).

Would love to know how this is implemented :) [Or can this be a bug?]

I have never seen such a thing before. This is like call-by-value but for stuff inside the function. Pretty weird I would say but definitely some form of performance boost.

Or perhaps this is the result of ReactJS caching the computation of the callback? If that is the case where can I learn more about it? And is there a way to flush the cache?